# HTML iFrame doesn't work

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed a website onto another website using the following code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.petarvasilev.com/"></iframe>
```

this fails I get the following error in the console

```
Refused to frame 'http://www.petarvasilev.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/drqjw080/) is a JsFiddle to try it out.

I checked the X-Frame-Options header and my site isn't sending one which leaves me oblivious as to why it doesn't work. Any help appreciated : )

Comment: That's odd the line works fine for me, have you tried running the `<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.petarvasilev.com/">
</iframe>` on a local file on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says:

> Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So perhaps change 'src' to 'frame-src'?

And please put your code in a jsfiddle (or pastebin or whatever), and provide a link.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/v0md82t5/1/

I added a double slash before the url. The problem now is that it complains about the DNS, I don't know if it's broken or if it's a problem with doing it inside a jsfiddle. Edit: I'm currently at work so can't look into it further right now.